# PyAudio play continuous stream in a thread and let change the frequency

Tags: python, audio, python-multithreading, pyaudio

I don't have the experience with threading at all.

All I want to do is to play a sound and be able to change the tone (frequency) in the meantime, using GUI.

This code plays a continuous stream without any peaks or distortions:

```
class Stream:
    def __init__(self, sample_rate):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.sample_rate = sample_rate

        # for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                                  channels=1,
                                  rate=sample_rate,
                                  output=True)
        self.samples = 0.

    def create_sine_tone(self, frequency, duration):
        # generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
        self.samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(self.sample_rate * duration) * frequency
                               / self.sample_rate)).astype(np.float32)

    def play_sine_tone(self, volume=1.):
        """
        :param frequency:
        :param duration:
        :param volume:
        :param sample_rate:
        :return:
        """

        # play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively)
        while 1:
            self.stream.write(volume * self.samples)

    def terminate(self):
        self.p.terminate()

    def finish(self):
        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.stream.close()
```

This code creates GUI. In`left_click` and `right_click` the `create_sine_tone()` creates a new frequency wave. However, as I understand, it modifies the memory that is used by `threading` in `play_sine_tone` and the program crashes.

```
def main():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Piano reference")
    window.geometry('350x200')

    s = Stream(44100)

    lbl = Label(window, text="A4")
    lbl.grid(column=2, row=1)

    def left_click(frequency):
        s.create_sine_tone(frequency, 1.)
        t = threading.Thread(target=s.play_sine_tone, args=(1,))
        t.start()
        lbl.configure(text=frequency)

    def right_click(frequency):
        s.create_sine_tone(frequency, 1.)
        t = threading.Thread(target=s.play_sine_tone, args=(1,))
        t.start()
        lbl.configure(text=frequency)

    btn1 = Button(window, text="<<", command=lambda: left_click(100))
    btn2 = Button(window, text=">>", command=lambda: right_click(200))

    btn1.grid(column=0, row=0)
    btn2.grid(column=1, row=0)

    window.mainloop()
```

How can I modify the wave so the program won't crash? Maybe I could close the thread before changing the frequency?

Comment: You r on right track, You can either close the existing thread playing sound after new frequency selection and before playing new frequency. OR, Don't use threads at all and keep track of peaks and let the existing frequency complete its peak before kicking off new one. That way you won't get clicking sound upon frequency shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is play different tones that can be controlled using GUI, you may not need threads.

[PySimpleGUI](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides an super easy to use GUI builder based on Tkinter (and other tools). Best of all it provides actions based on event that are driven by GUI components.

On the other hand use of [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) gives us easy way to create different tones and play them.
pydub `_play_with_simpleaudio` method allows us to play tones using simpleAudio in a non-blocking way.

GUI Controls:

- '>>' chooses next frequency in multiples of 200 Hz.
- '<<' chooses previous frequency in multiples of 100 Hz.
- 'X' to exit gui.

The only issue I observed was slight clicking sounds on frequency shift.That may need further work.

Following working code is based on above packages.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg      
from pydub.generators import Sine
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import _play_with_simpleaudio
import time

sr = 44100  # sample rate
bd = 16     # bit depth
l  = 10000.0     # duration in millisec

sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('BluePurple')
silent = AudioSegment.silent(duration=10000)
FREQ = 200

def get_sine(freq):
  #create sine wave of given freq
  sine_wave = Sine(freq, sample_rate=sr, bit_depth=bd)

  #Convert waveform to audio_segment for playback and export
  sine_segment = sine_wave.to_audio_segment(duration=l)

  return sine_segment

# Very basic window.  Return values as a list      
layout = [
              [sg.Button('<<'), sg.Button('>>')],
              [sg.Text('Processing Freq [Hz]:'), sg.Text(size=(15,1), justification='center', key='-OUTPUT-')]
          ]

window = sg.Window('Piano reference', layout)

count = 0
play_obj = _play_with_simpleaudio(silent)

while 100 <= FREQ <= 20000 :  # Event Loop
    count += 1
    event, values = window.Read()

    if event in  (None, 'Exit'):
        break
    if event == '<<':
      if not FREQ < 100:
        FREQ -= 100
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update(FREQ)

    if event == '>>':
      if not FREQ > 20000:
        FREQ += 200
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update(FREQ)

    print(event, FREQ)

    sound = get_sine(FREQ)

    try:
      play_obj.stop()
      time.sleep(0.1)
      sound = sound.fade_in(100).fade_out(100)
      play_obj = _play_with_simpleaudio(sound)
      time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      play_obj.stop_all()


window.close()
```

Result:

```
$ python3 pygui3.py 
Playing >> 400 Hz
Playing >> 600 Hz
Playing >> 800 Hz
Playing << 700 Hz
Playing << 600 Hz
```

GUI:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is the answer to my question but it solves my problem. Next time I'll look for better tools rather than to fight with almost working code too long.

Comment: I was able to remove the sleeps and it worked with no problems.  It didn't help the clicks.  It seems like those are from the "stop" call because if I remove the call to stop, I don't hear a click.  The tones all play on top of themselves, but they each start without the click.  I also tried without the fade_in and fade_out and that seemed to improve the clicks. Maybe it masks it a little by immediately starting the next tone?

Comment: yeah, I observed same. the stop call abruptly stops the tone and there is a delay in restart that causes the click. though It plays beautifully on top of each other producing harmonics. Perhaps try to stop previous after starting next one might work.May need two play_obj.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the answer. What I know:

1. There are "clicks" in the looping sound. One has to generate the full period of the signal
2. You can use the `stream` with `callback` so the threading is moved under the hood of `PyAudio`. Using it I am able to run the program in the accepted way
3. I had some ideas with creating two threading objects that will be the fields of `Stream` class. Then they can use 2 different streams and threads to start and stop. I wasn't able to make it work though - I think the threads are not waiting for the `finish()`

Comment: This is not an answer, You may want to take these comments and add to your question or post separately as "comments" under your question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave it because there are some other comments and answers already, and I don't want to do the mess, but I'll definitely remember about it next time